# Python паркинг разных сайтов в один Эксель файл

Tags: python, парсер, parse

Подскажите, как парсить данные с разных сайтов в один Эксель файл? Или возможно подскажете лучшее решение (возможно база данных).
Задача спарсить цены на одни и те же товары ряда интернет магазинов в одно место, сравнить с "идеальной" ценой и подсветить если цена больше или меньше "идеальной".

В таблице проще всего наглядно, мне кажется, т.к. нужно видеть наименование сайта, название товара и его цену.

Comment: Вместо эксель используйте лучше pandas. Парсер реализуйте с помощью BeautifulSoup4

Comment: да я сам парсер уже написал, но парсит он с конкретного сайта, создавая при этом Эксель файл, а вот как последующие парсинги в этот Эксель добавлять, а не новый создавать?